# How to enable message and trace logging together using circular tracing library?

Tags: wcf, logging, trace

In order to reduce svc logging files size of my wcf project, I made a research and I found 'CircularTracing' library which is a template created by Microsoft; In [their documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/circular-tracing) they added an example of tracelogging, but in my case I need to make a message logging in order to check the inputs filled by our developers; I tried to enable tracing alone --> it worked successfully and 2 log files were generated; I tried to enable message logging  alone also it worked successfully;

**BUT** when I tried to make them work both together --> he library did not generate 2 web_Trace files log, only web_Trace00.cvclog is generated and its size can overpass the max size; In addition of that the library has generated 2 messages log files but without respecting the max file size;

[image]

Below is my web.config code:

```
  <system.diagnostics>    
      <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing" >
          <listeners>
            <add name="CircularMessageListener" />
          </listeners>
        </source>   
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
          <listeners>
            <add name="CircularTraceListener" />
          </listeners>
        </source>
      </sources>    
      <sharedListeners>
        <add name="CircularMessageListener" type="Microsoft.Samples.ServiceModel.CircularTraceListener, CircularTraceListener, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
            initializeData="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyProject\Log\web_messages.svclog" maxFileSizeKB="20" />
        <add name="CircularTraceListener" type="Microsoft.Samples.ServiceModel.CircularTraceListener, CircularTraceListener, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
            initializeData="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyProject\Log\web_Trace.svclog" maxFileSizeKB="20" /> 
         </sharedListeners>    
      <trace autoflush="true" />  
    </system.diagnostics>
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that for message log file: some messages length is bigger then 20 KB, that's why message logging file became bigger then 20, after that the other file logs the data as it is expected;
Concerning trace log file: I don't know why the other file is not created, I appreciate if somebody can help me to discover the problem... but I ended up by using one file for both logging methods:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="CircularMessageTraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
          <listeners>
            <add name="CircularMessageTraceListener" />
          </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="CircularMessageTraceListener" type="Microsoft.Samples.ServiceModel.CircularTraceListener, CircularTraceListener, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
          initializeData="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyProject\Log\web_messages_trace.svclog" maxFileSizeKB="20" />      
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
```

In this way I can have 2 web_messages_trace generated logging files, I hope this can help anybody;